# Non-linear systems - how to keep track of unknowns from delegates?

Tags: c#, arrays, design-patterns, data-structures, delegates

This might sound like a maths questions but it is really more of a programming design question.

Imagine I have already implemented in C# a multidimensional root solver to find the unknowns of the following system, made from equations that I pass as delegates:

delegate 1) x4 + f(x4,x2,x3) -2 = 0

delegate 2) g(x1,x2) - 0.5 = 0

delegate 3) h(x1,x2) + x1*x3 - 5 = 0

delegate 4) x3*x4 - 2 = 0

Here, f g and h are some functions that return a float. The way the solver works is try different combinations of an input vector [a, b, c, d] corresponding to the union of all unknowns provided by the delegates, following some algorithm until all roots are found by iteration.

My problem is that each delegate of the above system is provided by a different class. This is actually a problem because the delegate number 1, which is a function defined in a different class elsewhere, needs to now that its parameters x2,x3,x4 correspond to the values b,c,d from the input vector... but it doesn't know that unless there exists some kind of mapping defined somewhere(?).

It would seem that there is a **dependency** between the solver and the delegates provided by each class. Is there a way that I can design my system so that each function knows where to get the corresponding x values from, so that the solver can do its work? I have been thinking of implementing hash-tables and create identifiers for each parameter but it all seems quite naff to me.

In practice, I will be working with a system with over 1000 equations and 1000 unknowns with the problems above described.

Is there a data structure or pattern that can help me here?

Comment: I am not quite understanding your problem. What do you mean that the class that provides 1 doesn't know `x1` exists. Do you mean it is never given `x1`? And if so, why is this a problem?

Comment: in each iteration, the solver generates a new vector [x1,x2,x3,x4] that is read by all the functions within the solver to know what their new value is, i.e. f1 needs a way of knowing where x2, x3 and x4 are in that vector so that it can calculate its new value... but f1 has been defined previously in a different class in such a way that it receives 3 arguments, not 4! how can f1 know that it needs to read into positions 2,3 and 4??

Comment: Are they not in order (`x1` is at index 0, `x2` at index 1 and so on)? I'm assuming not otherwise there wouldn't be an issue. Do you have any limitations? Could you, for example, use a Dictionary instead of an array?

Comment: Note that the functions 1), 2), ...n) are passed as delegates, and so its arguments are unaware of where the data is coming from, they just receive a certain number of arguments. Imagine that the solver is passed a vector of a 1000 positions. How does the delegate know where to get right parameter from, out of those 1000 values? It would not make sense to sort the arguments, they could all be completely different and/or unrelated and thus sorting only complicates the problem more IMO....

Comment: If I have understood correctly, then your only options are either to A: pass them in order (meaning `x1` is first, `x2` is second and so on, or B: use a Dictionary and do something along the lines of `float x1 = dict["x1"];`. Something similar to B could be achieved using some sort of Tuple or Pair as well.

Comment: Just do the way other libraries do this.  Like [Microsoft Solver Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.solvers(v=vs.93).aspx), note how it keeps a separate class to store solver parameters.  And hey, consider using it.

Comment: Something needs to know how to map vector elements to the parameters of the delegate.  That mapping can be done 1) by convention (e.g. everything just uses the order of the elements in the vector) 2) can be encoded coded as an algorithm.  In case 2, that algorithm could just be implemented as part of the code that calls the delegates, or it could in a separate class/function which has the logic to determine that mapping.  But unless a standard convention is defined, then you'll need to code a mapping algorithm somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Having a bit of trouble understanding the problem, but I suspect it would be solved by redefining your equations with some 0 coefficients, e.g.

delegate 1) x1 * 0 + x4 + f(x4, x2, x3) - 2 = 0

delegate 2) x2 * 0 + x3 * 0 + g(x1, x2) - 0.5 = 0

delegate 3) x4 * 0 + h(x1,x2) + x1 * x3 - 5 = 0

delegate 4) x1 * 0 + x2 * 0 + x3 * x4 - 2 = 0

The above will produce exactly the same results without the ambiguity of how to read the vector.  This sidesteps the problem because all delegates will have the same arguments.

Comment: The inconvenient I see with this solution is that the total number of unknowns is not known until all equations are put together inside the solver. This is because each class plugging its delegates into the solver contributes with a certain number of equations and unknowns.... but it could be that some of these new unknowns are already part of the solver! Thus it becomes difficult then to redefine my equations if I don't know where my parameters are going to be positioned in the final input array to the solver... I hope I made my problem a bit clearer now.